# How do I define a Python class that I can use with the with statement?

Tags: python

I understand that `StringIO` acts like a file object, duck-typing what you would get from `open('somefile.txt')`.

Now I want to use `StringIO` with the `with` statement:

```
with StringIO('some string') as fh: # fh as in "file handle"
    data = [stuff from stuff in fh.read()]
```

But Python complains that type `StringIO` does not have an `__exit__` method. After subclassing `StringIO`:

```
class MyStringIO(StringIO):
    def __exit__(self):
        self.close()
```

I now get an exception about not having an `__enter__` method. How do I define the `__enter__` method? What does Python expect from a class that can be used with the `with` statement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to write a [context manager](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types). If you don't want to write the whole protocol, there's a simplified way around it using the [contextlib.contextmanager](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#module-contextlib) decorator.

Comment: I was just writing out an example using contextlib.closing, and you beat me to it..

Comment: Note, for your case (where you just want to close the object), it would probably be simpler to use `contextlib.closing`.

Comment: @DSM: Lol... you beat me to commenting on contextlib.closing :D

Comment: `contextlib.closing` keeps it simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just to give an example where it would be overkill do use contextlib, which is more
for use with generators:

Here is a nice and useful example of a context manager.
I found it in David Beazley's blog:

http://dabeaz.blogspot.de/2010/02/context-manager-for-timing-benchmarks.html

and just modified it a little bit to use the best timer per platform,
a trick that I use from the [timeit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module:

```
# benchmark.py
import timeit
class benchmark(object):
    from timeit import default_timer as timer
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __enter__(self):
        self.start = self.timer()
    def __exit__(self, ty, val, tb):
        end = self.timer()
        print("%s : %0.3f seconds" % (self.name, end-self.start))
        return False
```

Now that gives you a context manager that you can use like this:

```
with benchmark('algorithm 1'):
    ... (some computation)
with benchmark('other approach'):
    ... (some other computation)
```

and you get your output printed.
I liked this example and wanted to share it.

Answer (score 0):

you define the `__enter__` method just as you did with `__exit__`. these are the two methods needed for an object to be used with the `with` statement, see [this](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) for more info.